# ChartElementFunction is not working properly with BarOrigin in Histogram

Tags: plotting, color, data, charts

MMA12.3.0.0 Win10 64.

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 5000], 500, 
     ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle", AspectRatio -> 1, 
     ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

now if I add `BarOrigin -> Left` it becomes black

```
Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 2], 5000], 500, 
 ChartElementFunction -> "GradientScaleRectangle", AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True, BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: By default in low bins, chart elements have a black stroke and on high numbers, they don't but with `BarOrigin -> Left` stokes exist unconditionally which becomes a problem with a high number of bins. You can fix it by adding `ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[None]`. (Version 13.1)